# Logstash to elasticsearch ssl configuration

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm getting errors with ssl connections from logstash to elasticsearch.
in elasticsearch I'm seeing this:

```
> 2019-02-21T15:39:22.488125445Z [2019-02-21T15:39:22,487][WARN
> ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [05w2lDl] http client
> did not trust this server's certificate, closing connection [id:
> 0xc1159c29, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9200 ! R:/10.10.0.22:49470]
```

on logstash I'm seeing this:

```
2019-02-21T15:49:26.052155453Z [2019-02-21T15:49:26,051][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"https://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:443/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [https://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:443/][Manticore::ClientProtocolException] PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"}
```

logstash.conf

```
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => [ "https://elasticsearch:443" ]
ssl => true
cacert => '/usr/share/logstash/config/certs/service.crt'
user => 'elastic'
password => ''
}

}
```

logstash.yml

```
http.host                               : 0.0.0.0
path.config                             : /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.ca   : /usr/share/logstash/config/certs/ca.crt
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.url      : "https://elasticsearch:443"
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username : "logstash_system"
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password : "..."
```

elasticsearch.yml

```
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled : true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode : certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled : true
xpack.ssl.key : /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/service.key
xpack.ssl.certificate : /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/service.crt
xpack.ssl.certificate_authorities : /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/ca.crt
```

These keys used to work... I just upgraded from 6.0.0 to 6.6.1.

I'm willing to start over with the certificates
should I instead do something with keystore and truststore from the documents?
Any thoughts??
Thanks,
Chris

Comment: There's a blog from Elastic providing step by step guide on configuring TLS between ELK stack components, may be follow that: https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-setup-tls-for-elasticsearch-kibana-logstash-filebeat-with-offline-install-in-linux

This is for stack version 6.x up until 6.7